# Android Layouts, Table, Relative and Linear, i am confused in their differences

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have read many articles regarding layout, but I am still quitely confused. My questions are:

- When to use relative layout? Example?
- When to use table layout and why we can't use it instead of relative layout?
- When to use linear layout?

I just need brief answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***When use which layout?***

I think It depends on your UI, *and most important thing that how you create optimized layout*.

*From definition : -*

***LinearLayout –*** designed to display child View controls in a single row or column. This is a very handy layout method for creating forms.

***RelativeLayout –*** designed to display child View controls in relation to each other. For instance, you can set a control to be positioned “above” or “below” or “to the left of” or “to the right of” another control, referred to by its unique identifier. You can also align child View controls relative to the parent edges.

***TableLayout –*** designed to organize child View controls into rows and columns. Individual View controls are added within each row of the table using a TableRow layout View (which is basically a horizontally oriented LinearLayout) for each row of the table.

References :

[Creating Efficient Layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)

[Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

And most important [Hierarchy Viewer](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-tools-using-the-hierarchy-viewer/)

Comment: For example i have to make a costing calculator having 10 fields, which layout i should use?   Thanks in advance

Comment: This can be easy using LinearLayout, and if you are good to use RelativeLayout then use this.

Answer (score 1):

at first there is some confusion about these layouts but as you start playing with these three layouts u will get idea where to use what.. I worked on relative-layout the most. 
Consider i want to use a widget always at bottom of screen then with table or linear layout this is not possible always.. without feeling screen other two can not make item at bottom but relative can do.use of any type of layout depends on your screen requirements.

Comment: so you point your widget towards bottom menu or what, how can you take this benefit from relative layout and what are its other uses, with respect to your experience...?

Comment: See if i want some buttons or controls at bottom of screen always at bottom then i use layout_alignParentBottom attribute in relative layout... likewise you can customize. I suggest you to explore thses layouts while playing with them

Answer (score 0):

I started out using relativelayout. But recently I've switched to using mostly linearlayout.

The reason is kind of hard to explain, but take this as an example: Say I want a layout that has two images centered in the middle of the screen. Both images should take up 1/4 of the screen width and 1/4 of the screen height. This is impossible to do with relativelayout assuming you want it to work exactly the same on all devices. But you can do this with Linearlayout. By creating vertical and horizontal parents, you can create "boxes". To accomplish this you must learn about weigthsum and weigth. Parent layouts should have the weigthsum attribute and children should have the weight attribute.

Anyway, my point: Relativelayout is easy to use but it's also deceptive. You may think that your layout will look exactly alike on all device, but most likely, they won't look alike. The reason for this is:

- With relativelayout you must define size with either dp or px(assuming you don't fill parent or wrap content).
- Different devices have different aspect ratios.

I hoped that helped in terms of understanding relative and linearlayout.